# Implementing datatables with data in json format from firebase

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, datatables

I am a little new to angular and I have been trying for a while now to display data from firebase into a datatable. Following a tutorial [from this link](https://medium.com/apprendre-le-web-avec-lior/angular-5-and-jquery-datatables-fd1dd2d81d99) but, the rows show but without the data. I would be grateful for your help

**This is my HTML**

```
<div  class="container">
        <table class="table table-hover table-responsive" cellspacing="0">
          <thead class="text-me">
                <tr>
                    <th>Programme</th>
                    <th>Course Code</th>
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th>Block</th>
                    <th>Course Name</th>
                    <th>Course Material</th>
                    <th>Slides</th>
                    <th>Videos</th>
                    <th>Enrollment</th>
                    <th>Comments</th>
                </tr>

          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let blockCourse of blockCourseList">
                  <td>{{blockCourse.programme}}</td>
                  <td>{{blockCourse.courseCode}}</td>
                  <td>{{blockCourse.year}}</td>
                  <td>{{blockCourse.block}}</td>
                  <td>{{blockCourse.courseName}}</td>
                  <td>{{blockCourse.courseMat}}</td>
                  <td>{{blockCourse.slides}}</td>
                  <td>{{blockCourse.video}}</td>
                  <td>{{blockCourse.enrollment}}</td>
                  <td>{{blockCourse.comment}}</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**This my  block-course-list component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BlockCoursesService } from '../../shared/block-courses.service';
import { BlockCourse } from '../../shared/block-course.model';
import { element } from 'protractor';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'datatables.net';
import 'datatables.net-bs4';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-block-course-list',
  templateUrl: './block-course-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./block-course-list.component.scss']
})
export class BlockCourseListComponent implements OnInit {
  blockCourseList: BlockCourse[];
  clients: any[];
  // Our future instance of DataTable
  dataTable: any;
  constructor(private blockCoursesService: BlockCoursesService, private chRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let x = this.blockCoursesService.getData();
    x.snapshotChanges().subscribe((item: any[]) => {
        this.blockCourseList = item;

        // this.clients = item;
        this.chRef.detectChanges();
        const table: any = $('table');
        this.dataTable = table.DataTable();

        item.forEach(element => {
          let y = element.payload.toJSON();
          y['$key'] = element.key;
          this.blockCourseList.push(y as BlockCourse);
        });
    });
    }
    onEdit(blk: BlockCourse) {
      this.blockCoursesService.selectedCourse = Object.assign({}, blk);
    }
    onDelete(key: string) {
      if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?') === true) {
        this.blockCoursesService.deleteBlockCourse(key);
      }
    }
}
```

This is the block-course model

```
export class BlockCourse {
    $key: string;
    courseCode: string;
    year: string;
    block: string;
    courseName: string;
    programme: string;
    courseMat: string
    slides: string;
    video: string;
    enrollment: string;
    comment: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

For displaying data which is received by asynchronous code, you have to use `async` pipe. Just put `async` pipe into the `*ngFor` loop and everything should work as expected:

```
// ...
<tr *ngFor="let blockCourse of blockCourseList | async">
// ...
```

The `async` pipe can be used if a value is set via an asynchronous way or for unwrapping `Observable` and `Promise` objects.

#### Note

When I look at the code, I don't understand why `blockCourseList` is assigned twice. First the received `item` array is assigned and afterwards all objects in `item` are iterated and added to `blockCourseList` again. That happens in following code:

Just think about this.

```
    x.snapshotChanges().subscribe((item: any[]) => {
        this.blockCourseList = item;

        // this.clients = item;
        this.chRef.detectChanges();
        const table: any = $('table');
        this.dataTable = table.DataTable();

        item.forEach(element => {
          let y = element.payload.toJSON();
          y['$key'] = element.key;
          this.blockCourseList.push(y as BlockCourse);
        });
    });
```

Comment: I've removed the this.blockCourseList = item. but adding the async to the code still did not change anything

Comment: Ok, if the rows are displayed without the data you should check if the data is valid. Try to output every `BlockCourse` object into console in the `forEach` loop.